# Gutenberg blocks - template_lock with several post type

Tags: block-editor

I use `template_lock` to lock some Gutenberg blocks. But I would like to use it in three differents post type.

`get_post_type_object();` admit only string, no array.

How to use several post type without repeat three times the same function please ?

```
function wp_template_lock_subject_imposed() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'subject-imposed' );

    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'acf/text-introduction'),
        array( 'acf/text-paragraph')
    );

    $post_type_object->template_lock = false;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wp_template_lock_subject_imposed' );

function wp_template_lock_subject_free() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'subject-free' );

    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'acf/text-introduction'),
        array( 'acf/text-paragraph')
    );

    $post_type_object->template_lock = false;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wp_template_lock_subject_free' );

function wp_template_lock_dissertation() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'dissertation' );

    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'acf/text-introduction'),
        array( 'acf/text-paragraph')
    );

    $post_type_object->template_lock = false;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wp_template_lock_dissertation' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question than a WordPress one but you could do the following:

```
function wp_template_lock_example() {
    // Make an array of your post types
    $post_types = array('subject-imposed', 'subject-free', 'dissertation');

    // Loop the array and apply the template details to each.
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
        $post_type_object->template = array(
            array( 'acf/text-introduction'),
            array( 'acf/text-paragraph')
        );

       $post_type_object->template_lock = false;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_template_lock_example' );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I didn't know how to put my post types in an array. Now I understand. It works perfectly, thank you for your help.